# How to obtain streamslines from velocity field data points

Tags: finite-difference

I managed to solved a lid-driven cavity flow using LB code. It gave me the velocity field data points.

Now I have to obtain streamlines too, of course from the obtained velocity field.

Besides, I know the theory of Potential Flow as well as all of the associated relations.

How can I directly draw the streamlines of this flow without solving a Poisson equation. If numerical integration must to be used (as I guess), How should I do handle with partial derivatives?

Comment: There are algorithms that already compute the streamlines for you. Can't you use one of those?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest thing to do is to use a visualization package or something with built-in vis capabilities. [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/streamline.html?refresh=true), [ParaView](https://www.scorec.rpi.edu/wiki/Using_ParaView#Stream_Tracer), and [VisIt](http://www.visitusers.org/index.php?title=Streamline_Plots_in_VisIt) all support plotting streamlines natively, and the latter two are freely available.

If you want to plot them yourself, they are usually integrated using a psuedo-time integration method from seed points such that

$$
\frac{dx(s)}{ds} = u(x(s),t)
$$

for $t$ fixed and some initial point $x(0)=x_0$. If the flow is steady, then you can drop the $t$.

Comment: Thanks. I am willing to do it on my own (coding). Can you give me at least some sources?

Comment: I recommend that you don't unless you are working towards becoming an expert in scientific visualization. Integrating streamlines by hand is actually non-trivial, since your sample points will be between grid points and will also require some sort of interpolation to find the right velocities for each step. Experts at this have put in all the work for you already.

Comment: Yes. Actually I read A. A. Mohamad's book on Lattice Boltzmann Method. There he do this with a few lines of code. One thing more, What about Tecplot? Does it have this feature?

Comment: Yes, and every other visualization program that takes vector data.

Answer (score 0):

The [CGAL library](http://www.cgal.org/) has a package for this purpose.  See [their documentation for details and references](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Stream_lines_2/index.html#Chapter_2D_Placement_of_Streamlines).